# How to make a solution refer to a different form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm creating a windows application and deleted the original form design. I created a new form for it to use, but it does not recognize it. I'm new to computer science and java; I'm using C# for the first time.

I've gone through the solution and changed all mentions of "Form1" to "Form2" and I've searched the entire solution with control + f for Form1.resx and have come up with no results. I visited another stack overflow forum that said the ".csproj is corrupted." This did not help. It doesn't list any lines of code that the error is on.

My error message:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Form1.resx". Could not find file 'C:\Users\Human\source\repos\Satisfactory_Calc\Satisfactory_Calc\Form1.cs'. Satisfactory_Calc`

I need the solution to run Form2.

Comment: Is that the error message you are getting?  Or is it from the other SO question you referenced?

Comment: It is the error message i am getting. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing that I had already deleted the form, I simply had to stumble upon the solution explorer and right click form1 and select "exclude from solution"